# Microsoft Azure: How to Implement ASP.NET Transient Fault Handling Without Enterprise Application Block

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-sql-database

When we first migrated to Azure, transient fault handling via the Enterprise Application Block 5.0 was the best game in town.  We use it to automatically perform retries when getting an Azure SQL Connection, accessing ASP.NET Session objects and accessing ASP.NET Application objects.  To do so, we make use of the following classes respectively:

- ReliableSqlConnection from the Application Block
- Our own ReliableApplication class that extends Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache by applying the Application Block cache RetryPolicy when accessing Application objects
- Our own ReliableSession class that extends HttpContext.Current.Session by applying the Application Block cache RetryPolicy when accessing Session objects.

Now according to [Microsoft's Transient Fault Handling Patterns and Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh675232.aspx) as of March 2014:

> Recent versions of SDKs for both Azure Storage and Azure Service Bus natively support retries. It is recommended to use these instead of the Transient Fault Handling Application Block

What Azure SDK classes should we use to replace our dependencies on deprecated Enterprise Application Block Transient Fault Handling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow the following blog posts to implement retry logic(These are ADO.NET samples but you can replicate the logic in the language of your choice)
https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/ee336243.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn961167.aspx

The first one is implementing retry logic using the Enterprise Library and the second one shows you how to implement retry logic using custom code.

To answer your question :

*What Azure SDK classes should we use to replace our dependencies on deprecated Enterprise Application Block Transient Fault Handling?
You will have to use retry logic to improve connection resiliency. Unfortunately there is no Azure SDK that you can use currently to implement retry logic to connect to Azure SQL DB.*

Let me know if this makes sense.

Best,

Meet Bhagdev

Program Manager, Microsoft

Comment: meet-bhagdev, And I suppose a variant of the first link that you provided could be used to retry accessing Session and Application objects.  thank you!

Comment: You are welcome user773906. Let me know if that does the trick for you and mark proposal as an answer for future reference.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This site has examples for the native client support for each service

https://github.com/mspnp/azure-guidance/blob/master/Retry-Service-Specific.md

Comment: The above link:

1)  Applies to Azure Redis Cache that I am not using and

2) For Azure SQL connection retry, it referred me to [Windows Azure SQL Database Performance and Elasticity Guide][1].  And that referred me to [The Transient Fault Handling Application Block][2].  So, it looks like I can't get rid of the Application Block until I replace all of my ADO.NET code with Entity Framework.

[1]:http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3507.windows-azure-sql-database-performance-and-elasticity-guide.aspx
[2]:https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh680934(v=pandp.50).aspx

Comment: @user773906 As I understand it the Transient Fault Handling Block is not completely deprecated. For Storage and Service Bus (which I assumed you are using from the patterns and practices quote) it is, in favour of the client retry policy. For Sql Database without EF I believe it is still recommended practice to use the Transient Fault Handling Block. Personally, I continue to use TFHB because as you say it works so well and I'm not sure what benefits if any the client retry has. All personal choice of course.

Comment: I did follow the advice to move the caching to the Redis service which has to date performed brilliantly  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn766201.aspx

Comment: I surmise from the above comments that the Transient Fault Handling Application Block is still needed for ADO.NET database connections and the distributed local cache for our two VMs.  Thank you.